# How can i wrap 2 MySql queries into one?

Tags: php, mysql

hI I Want to wrap the following mysql queries into one in my php file.

the first is:

```
$query = 'SELECT cat_name FROM #__tt_cats WHERE cat_published = 1 AND cat_name LIKE ' .         $db->quote('%'.$q.'%');
```

and the second is:

```
$query = 'SELECT link_name FROM #__tt_links WHERE link_name LIKE ' . $db- >quote('%'.$q.'%');
```

How can i do this ???

Comment: Take a look at UNION or UNION ALL. (That will combine the cat_name and link_name into the same resultset/column though)

Comment: @Laoujin can you provide an example for the above queries?? Thanks

Comment: Check Damodaran's answer. It might be a good idea to replace your string-concatenation with [prepared SQL statements](http://be2.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) in order to avoid [SQL-injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2):

Check [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
$query = 'SELECT cat_name FROM #__tt_cats WHERE cat_published = 1 AND cat_name LIKE ' .         $db->quote('%'.$q.'%')
$query += ' UNION '
$query += 'SELECT link_name FROM #__tt_links WHERE link_name LIKE ' . $db- >quote('%'.$q.'%');
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION.